# Remove the Shipping method name using phtml code

Tags: shipping

visit this [link1](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html)

enter "110001" as zip code and click on "check " button.

you can see : "Shipping Charges : Rs. 30.00"

[image]

"shipping charges" is Name of Shipping method we gave in backend.

I want to remove this text "shipping charges :"

```
<div class="block block-shipping-estimate block-shipping-results">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span>
        <?php 
    //  echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getShiptitle(); 
        ?>
        </span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
<?php if ($this->getResult()):?>
        <dl>
            <?php foreach ($this->getResult() as $code => $_rates): ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                        <li<?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()) echo ' class="error-msg"';?>>
                           <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                <?php echo $_rate->getErrorMessage() ?>
                           <?php else: ?>
                                <?php echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() ?>
                                <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                                <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                    (<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                <?php endif; ?>
                           <?php endif ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php //echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml(); ?>
        <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getResult(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you even try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to comment this line: `<?php echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() ?>` in the **else** block, some line numbers would be good here to point out right place :)